# JQuery get a identifier of an object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get a tooltip staying up when hoovered, but I don't know anything to identify it by. Is there some way that I can find any identifier, so that I can have it close on mouseout instead of mouseout of the link?

It is related to my other question (which is more specific about tooltipsy): [How to make tooltipsy staying so a link in it can be clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735301/how-to-make-tooltipsy-staying-so-a-link-in-it-can-be-clicked/)

**Edit**: I'm using [Tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/) to create the tooltips (but I might change if someone can suggest another jQuery plugin that can do this for me.

What I want is for the tooltip to stay if I have the mouse on it, instead of it disappearing when the mouse leaves the element invoking the tooltip. The tooltip should contain clickable links.

js:

```
# NOTE: The hide property is only for me to make it stay longer, so that the links are clickable. It is not an accepted soloution.
$('.order_tooltip').tooltipsy({
    delay: 0,
    offset: [0,-1],
    hide: function (e, $el) { 
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                $el.hide();
            },
            1000
        );
    }
});
```

html:

```
<a href="/order/ordernr/{{ item.order_nr }}"
    title="Tooltip content" 
    class="order_tooltip" 
>link</a>
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. How is the tooltip created?

Comment: This question can't be answered without seeing your js code + HTML!

Comment: R u using jquery.tipsy.js ??? and you want to know that how to get tipsy on hover of element??

Comment: @nnnnnn using the plugin tooltipsy, link in the question, but if you have a better suggestion I'm listening..

Comment: @gdoron I added it, just that I use the plugin so the code creating it doesn't add much...

Comment: @PriyankPatel nope, tooltipsy. I want to know how to get the tooltip to stay when leaving the invoking element and hovering the tooltip instead so that I can click the links in the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to get the identifier and couldn't wait so I changed to another tooltip plugin called [simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) that provided the functionality that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onmouseover="youtipsyobject().show();" onmouseout="youtipsyobject().hide()">link</a>
```

and make by default hide.

Comment: Not really since I don't know youtipsyobject(), that was the problem.

Comment: The object seems to be generated with a random string as well so it's probably not possible to do this outside of the class code.

Comment: then first you need to know the basics of javascript first.

Comment: I do know the basics of javascript, I've been working with it for years, but not this kind of plugin integration. I at least know enough not to use onmouseover and onmouseout in a link instead of a handler for these events :)

Comment: Although this is a very good tooltip plugin, I used it personally in several projects. http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/
hope you find it useful

Comment: Thanks, I've used it before as well, but this time I found http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/ even more useful.